# Sum variables conditionally with loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop, sum, plyr, lapply

I realize this is a topic that's covered somewhat well but I couldn't find anything that approaches this specific concern:

I have a df with 800 columns, 10 iterations of 80 columns (each column represents an item) - Each column is named something like: `1_BL_PRE.1` `1_FU_PRE.1` `1_BL_PRE.1` `1_BL_POST.1` 
Where the first '1' indicates the item number and the second '1' indicates the iteration number.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to get the sums of specific groups of items from all 10 iterations.

As a short example let's say I want to take the 1st and 3rd item of `BL_PRE` and get the sum of all 10 iterations for those 2 items - how would I do this?

```
  subject   1_BL_PRE.1   2_BL_PRE.1   3_BL_PRE.1   1_BL_PRE.2   2_BL_PRE.2  
1   40002       3              4            3           1             2
2   40004       1              2            3           4             4
3   40006       4              3            3           3             1
4   40008       2              3            1           2             3
5   40009       3              4            1           2             3
```

Expected output (where A represents the sum of 1_BL_PRE.1, 3_BL_PRE.1, 1_BL_PRE.2 and so on):

```
subject     BL_PRE_A 
1   40002       12 
2   40004       14  
3   40006       15  
4   40008       20   
5   40009       12
```

My hunch is the solution is related to a for-loop or lappy (and I'm not familiar at all with either). I'm trying to work with `apply(finaldata,1,function(x) {sum(x ...)})` but I haven't been able to figure out the conditional statement for the function of sum.

If there's an implementation with plyr I'd be really curious to see what that looks like. (and if there's a thread that answers this, apologies and just re-direct!)

**Edited to include small example + code I'm trying to get to work

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a small reproducible example (5 to 10 columns with 10 rows or so) along with expected output?

Comment: Yea sorry, just realized I didn't do that, will also include the the apply function I'm trying to work with but failing

Comment: You may need 80 dataframes with 10 columns each within a single list. Then you can do something like `lapply(mylst, function(df) rowSums(df[, c(1, 5, 20)]))` and it will get the sum of those columns for all 80 items in a single line of code.

Comment: Just a doubt regarding the expected output.  Should all these sum together as all of them are BL_PRE

Comment: Can you explain how you got the expected output as it is not clear which columns are used for the sum

Comment: I think I clarified? 1st and 3rd columns in the example. In the actual data set it's the 1, 3, 5, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, and 19th columns and the 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 13, 15, 18, and 20th columns that I'm going to sum.

Comment: @MikaelRubin  Should there be a pattern in the column names where you are going to take the sum or is it just based on position?

Comment: @akrun just position

Comment: @MikaelRubin  So, in this current example, you are taking the 1st, 3rd and 5th, would it still have any pattern.  Your previous comment looks like not much pattern considering you are using `9, 10` and `6, 7, 8`  I am trying to figure out the positions of those 80 columns that you mentioned in the post.

Comment: @akrun, okay I see, sorry. Yes so the position is regular: it goes 1, 2, 3...20 (for the item number), then 1, 2, 3...10 (for the iteration number). But there are 4 different column names each with the same pattern...so 1_BL_PRE but after 1-20_BL_PRE.1 there is 1-20_BL_POST.1 then 1-20_FU_PRE.1 then 1-20_FU_PRE.1 THEN it goes 1-20_BL_PRE.2, 1-20_BL_POST.2 then 1-20_FU_PRE.2 then 1-20_FU_PRE.2 and so on. Does that clarify things?

Comment: In that case try `data.frame(c(df1[1], lapply(split.default(df1[-1], 
  rep(1:20, each=20, length.out=800)), rowSums, na.rm=TRUE)))`

Comment: You should really check out http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf